# Printing milliseconds of Java epoch returns 18000000?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

In Joda, if I print

```
DateTime(GregorianChronology.getInstance())
    .withYear(1970)
    .withMonthOfYear(1)
    .withDayOfMonth(1)
    .withHourOfDay(0)
    .withMinuteOfHour(0)
    .withSecondOfMinute(0)
    .withMillisOfSecond(0).getMillis();
```

I see `18000000` (this also happens to be 1/4th of `MILLIS_PER_DAY`, FWIW).

What I don't understand is that if the milliseconds represents the offset from the epoch which is defined as Jan-1970-01-01, then shouldn't the milliseconds be 0?

Comment: I has to do with the time zone portion of the date value

Comment: Ah good point. You mean whatever time zone Java is using happens to be +1/4th of a day?

Comment: For me, it's +10 hours.  Create a Date/Time value that has a GMT of 0 and see what you get

Comment: thanks @MadProgrammer, final DateTime instant = new DateTime(GregorianChronology.getInstance(DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT0"))).withYear(1970).withMonthOfYear(1).withDayOfMonth(1).withHourOfDay(0).withMinuteOfHour(0).withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0); does in fact give me 0. Can you add your point as an answer so I can accept and it can be here for others in the future?

Comment: good to hear. I've added answer as you've request ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the issue is related to the way Java dates include the time zone as part of there calculations.

For me, this means I'm +10 hours ahead of the epoc.

Try creating a Date/Time value that is set to 0 GMT.

Answer (score 2):

The epoch is Jan-1970-01-01 **`GMT`**. The instance you have, obviously has a different `DateTimeZone`. In fact it lookds like you're at GMT+5. (18000000 millis = 5 hours)

Answer (score 1):

The "epoch" is a specific and universal  **instant**, a point in the universe time (like, say the moment in which the Apollo XI landed on the moon). This reference point can be represented differently in different countries (and a martian could also represent it with his own calendar). For example, for the people in England (GMT), that's the moment  in which the hands of their clocks marked "00:00:00" and their (Gregorian) calendars marked "1/1/1970"; but that's just an example.

The line

```
DateTime(GregorianChronology.getInstance()).withYear(1970).withMonthOfYear(1)
    .withDayOfMonth(1).withHourOfDay(0).withMinuteOfHour(0)
    .withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0)
```

gives you the instant in which the clocks and the calendars in *your* country marked "00:00:00 1970-01-01". That's, in general, a different instant.